# Why UITableView does not display new data after tableView.reloadData()

Tags: swift, xml, xcode, uitableview

I have the code below. It works like this: the table loads news on XML. The `fetchXMLData ()` function is responsible for everything. I have implemented a menu through `UIStackView`. When you click on the menu item, the XML link changes (`feedURL` variable), the `fetchXMLData ()` function starts again, the table is cleared, and rebooted, but new data is not visible. Although `print ()` prints information about the number of downloaded sources.

In general, my question is: how to upload new data to the table? `tableView.reloadData ()` does not help, or am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

**MainViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var cityButtons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var feedUrl = "https://tass.ru/rss/v2.xml"
var listOfNewsVM = [XMLParserVM]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "ТАСС"

    fetchXMLData()

    //self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


    }


    func fetchXMLData() {
    XMLParserFactory.fetchData(url: feedUrl) { (listOfXMLVM, error)        in

        print("Fetch xml data")
        print(self.feedUrl)

        if error == nil {
            self.listOfNewsVM = listOfXMLVM!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
        }
    }
}
    }
      extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfNewsVM.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Segue to the second view controller
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegue", sender: self)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        let newsVM = listOfNewsVM[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = newsVM.title
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = newsVM.link
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        //cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        return cell

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // get a reference to the second view controller
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController

        // set a variable in the second view controller with the data to pass
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let row = indexPath.row
        let newsVM = listOfNewsVM[row]
        secondViewController.receivedData = newsVM.desc
        secondViewController.receivedTitle = newsVM.title
        secondViewController.receivedLink = newsVM.link

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    w@IBAction func handleSelection(_ sender: UIButton) {

    cityButtons.forEach { (button) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            button.isHidden = !button.isHidden
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.stack)
          })

    }

}
enum Citys: String {
    case topNews = "Топ новости"
    case businnesNews = "Новости бизнеса"

}

    @IBAction func cityTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let title = sender.currentTitle, let city = Citys(rawValue: title) else {
        return
    }

    switch city {
    case .topNews:

        feedUrl = "https://life.ru/xml/feed.xml"
        listOfNewsVM.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()
        fetchXMLData()


    default:

        feedUrl = "https://tass.ru/rss/v2.xml"
        fetchXMLData()


    }

    }
  }
```

**And XMLParserVM:**

```
import UIKit

class XMLParserFactory {
static func fetchData(url: String, withCallback completionHandler:    @escaping (_ listOfModels: [XMLParserVM]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    XMLParserClient.sharedInstance().fetchXMLData(for: url) { (newsModelList, error) in

        print("Fetch data  Factory ", newsModelList?.count ?? "0")

        if error == nil {
            var listOfNewsVM = [XMLParserVM]()
            newsModelList?.forEach { model in
                let parserVM = XMLParserVM.init(model)
                listOfNewsVM.append(parserVM)
            }
      //                for item in listOfNewsVM {
     //                    print("\(item.title) - \(item.link)")
    //                }
            completionHandler(listOfNewsVM, nil)
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
   }
  }

 class XMLParserVM {

var model:NewsModel?

init(_ model:NewsModel) {
    self.model = model
}

var title: String {
    if let _ = model {
        return (model?.title)!
    }
    return ""
}

var link: String {
    if let _ = model {
        return (model?.link)!
    }
    return ""
}

var desc: String {
    if let _ = model {
        return (model?.desc)!
    }
    return ""
}

q}
```

Comment: Possibly because `self.tableView.reloadData()` isn't called on main thread?

Comment: I post tableView.reloadData () after and before fetchXLData in viewDidLoad method, no result. XML Parse, but table not update.

Comment: I add  func refreshUI() { DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() } } before viewDidiLoad and call this function inside viewDidLoad, but and this did not bring result.

Comment: Okay, it's work, but old data in tableView not deleting after update (

Comment: Look your switch on city. reload is called before parse new data, and in the second case you parse data but never call reload (and didn't removed old data before parsing new ones).

Comment: No no, it's not working, can you help me please, show source code edit.